# Performance de query LIKE no MySQL

Tags: mysql, query, operadores, índices, operador-like

Existe alguma maneira de aumentar a performance de uma query com `LIKE '%string%'` no MySQL?

Sei que se o `LIKE` for `'string%'`, é mais rápido. O problema é quando o `%` está no começo da string. Tem algum tipo de índice que podemos criar para ter mais performance nessa query?

Comment: vc poderia usar http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html se suas strings forem grandes o suficiente. Imagino que internamente ele construa índices levando em conta todas as palavras do texto e talvez fique mais rápido

Comment: Um artigo relevante sobre escalabilidade de `LIKE` e `FULLTEXT`: http://makandracards.com/makandra/12813-performance-analysis-of-mysql-s-fulltext-indexes-and-like-queries-for-full-text-search

Comment: Você poderia migrar esse tipo de buscas pra um Search Engine, talvez Solr (http://lucene.apache.org/solr/)

Comment: Se quiser realmente "esticar o arco"... Faça um dicionário reverso com todas as palavras de cada registro. Isso requer um esforço de codificação a mais e uma estrutura e tanto. No entanto, é uma das técnicas que motores de busca usam para serem tão performáticos.

Answer (score 2):

Sua resposta é não. Conforme foi comentado, se não for usado o operador [MATCH](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-search.html) do Full Text search o índice não tem como otimizar ambos os lados da consulta conforme o [Use The Index, Luke!](http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/where-clause/searching-for-ranges/like-performance-tuning), não existe uma forma de se indexar, ou ordenar os valores para que sejam otimizados com o operador LIKE.

Comment: Na verdade você respondeu a minha pergunta e para mim a resposta é: sim, é possível: usando o operador MATCH em FULL_TEXT - ele só funciona para tabelas MyISAM em mysql < 5.6

Comment: Exato, ou o o innoBD

Answer (score 1):

Dependendo da aplicação uma alternativa poderia ser feita.
Imagine um site de venda de livros 
Vamos ter claro uma tabela de LIVROS (codigo,nome,autor,etc)
Uma tabela poderia ser criada LIVROS_PALAVRA_CHAVE (CODIGO_LIVRO,PALAVRA)

As palavras mais importantes da busca estariam nesta tabela com o uso de índice seria uma busca exata.

O problema é que nós usuários muita vezes não lembramos da grafia correta, mas isto nem o LIKE resolve.

Comment: Como os motores de busca/corretores ortográficos funcionam então?

Comment: Aí entra os "match.against" da vida que buscam por proximidade.

Comment: Basicamente como foi dito , otimizar LIKE e afins em geral é NÃO. E como procurar os óculos quando não se faz ideia de onde deixou com o agravante de estar vendo mal ...